# How to read configuration bit register from PIC?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, mplabx

I'm debugging and want to inspect

> CONFIG1H (CONFIGURATION REGISTER 1 HIGH)

of a PIC18F.  CONFIG1H does seem to be recongized as an SFR when I enter it into the Watch window.

After stopping at a breakpoint, you can open the configuration bits window:

> Window >> PIC Memory Views >> Configuration bits

but it's unclear whether those are cached in MPLABX or newly read from the MCU.

Comment: These config registers are special, and not directly accessible in the same way as sfr's.  Do you have the source code and/or source hex file available? Or are you reading out the code from the PIC?

Comment: Yes.  I'm mucking with configuration register and OSCCON settings for low speed USB but can only seem to get things working for the default full speed settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this ambiguity, you should embed the CONFIG register settings in your source code.  Then, when you compile your code, it embeds the settings into your hex file.

As you stated, you can view the Configuration Bits.  This is not to set them, however, as much as to assist you in formatting them for your code. Once you select what you want, click where it says "Generate Source Code":

[image: config]

It will give you formatted #pragma statements that you can copy directly into your source files:

[image: code]

Put these statements in the source code, outside of any function.  I put mine at the top of my main.c file.

Good luck!